# Finding integer points of parallel lines

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Given two numbers $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $gcd(a, b) = 1$, the set $P = \{(k \cdot a, k \cdot b) \; | \; k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is the intersection of points on the line $g: ax = by$ and the integer points $I = \{(x, y) \; | \; x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ in the plane.

We know that there is an infinite number of lines parallel to $g$, that also contain an individual infinite subset of integer points $I$.

**(How) can we *analytically* determine the integer point subsets of the two lines, that are *closest* to $g$?**

For clarification, see this figure for $a = -2$ and $b = 3$. $g$ is the blue line, $P$ is the set of blue dots. We are looking for the set of red and green dots.
[image]

You may notice that this is actually a very abstract problem of discrete mathematics, put into a geometric application.

For those interested: I came up with this problem while trying to solve [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5c76d04fdee0db3043b3c8f8) quiz on [codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line parallel to $\ g\ $ must be of the form $\ ax-by=c\ $, in which case its distance from $\ g\ $ is $\ \frac{|c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\ $.  If it contains any integer points, then $\ c\ $ must be an integer.  Since the lines $\ c_1: ax-by=1\ $ and $\ c_{-1}:ax-by=-1\ $ both contain an infinite number of integer points, they must be the lines closest to $\ g\ $ that do so.  You can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find an integer point $\ \left(x_0,y_0\right)\ $ on $\ c_1\ $ (i.e. such that $\ ax_0-by_0=1\ $).  The set of integer points on $\ c_1\ $ is then
$$
\left\{\left(x_0+kb, y_0+ka\right)\big|\,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\ ,
$$
and the set of integer points on $\ c_{-1}\ $ is
$$
\left\{\left(-x_0+kb, -y_0+ka\right)\big|\,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\ .
$$